# Python Expression cannot contain assignment for socket import

Tags: python, sockets

Running this code I get a traceback error that I don't understand. I've run this code before and it has worked. The error is in network.py.

Is self.client an expression?

I've been looking around the web for an answer but I haven't found anything. I also don't understand my code enough to troubleshoot it since I ran off of a tutorial.

I'm using pydroid.

network.py

```
import socket

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
        self.port = 1221
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.id = self.connect()

    def getPos(self):
        return self.id
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass
    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

game.py

```
import pygame
import network
dir(network)
clientNumber = 0
class Player():

    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

    def updateTouch(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.update()
    def update(self):
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

def read(str):
    str = str.split(",")
    return int(str[0]), int(str[1])

def make(tup):
    return str(tup[0]) + "," + str(tup[1])

def redrawWindow(win, player, player2):
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    player2.draw(win)
    player.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.display.flip()
 
def main():
    
 running = True
 n = network.Network()
 startPos = read(n.getPos())
 AttackOne = Player(startPos[0], startPos[1], 100, 100, (0,255,0))
 AttackTwo = Player(0, 0, 100, 100, (255,0,0))
 pygame.init()
 pygame.font.init()
    
 
 while running:
  AttackTwoPos = read(n.send(make((AttackOne.x, AttackOne.y))))
  AttackTwo.x = AttackTwoPos[0]
  AttackTwo.y = AttackTwoPos[1]
  AttackTwo.update()
  for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
    AttackOne.updateTouch(x - 50, y - 50)
    
    print(x, y)

  
  
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    running = False
    pygame.quit()
    
  redrawWindow(screen, AttackOne, AttackTwo)    
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Game/new.py", line 2, in <module>
    
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Game/network.py", line 5
    self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_S>
                                                ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Comment: The line in the traceback doesn't match the line in the code you showed us - notice how it's truncated, and has a `>` at the end?  You aren't running the code you think you are, and I suspect that a similar corruption to the code on the previous line is actually responsible for the syntax error.

Comment: Oh dang, I thought that was a cut off point. I'll rewrite it out and see what happens